# Fetch Specific data from text file

Tags: python-3.x

I have some data in a test file say `sample.txt` I need a new text file that has data like expected below:

```
1_name_JACK
1_details_score_1_1_1_1_1_1_1
```

**Expected data :**

```
JACK = 1_1_1_1_1_1_1
```

***Can anyone help me out ?***

Comment: What did you try? What was the problem? Why can you not simply open a text editor, enter `JACK = 1_1_1_1_1_1_1` and save?

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your question properly this might be a solution to your problem:

```
names = [line.split('name_')[-1].replace('\n', ' = ') for line in open('Input') if 'name' in line]
# names -> ['JACK = ']
scores = [line.split('score_')[-1] for line in open('Input') if 'score' in line] 
# scores -> ['1_1_1']

with open("Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
    for l in range(len(names)):
        text_file.write(names[l] + scores[l])
# Output-> JACK = 1_1_1
```